# running docker request from php

Tags: php, docker, fedora, pdftk

I have encapsulated pdftk (PDF tool kit) as program that can be run inside of a fedora docker image.  This allows me to run pdftk on a newer AWS AMI image that does not support pdftk.  When replacing pdftk in our PHP program with the docker run command, it works great when running the PHP program from the command line, but when running it as a cron job or as a mailbox command, docker will not run.  I have made the cron and mailbox users part of the docker group, checked permissions and paths, but still no joy.

The exec PHP command looks like:

`$command = 'docker run -i -t --privileged -v /var/www/mbx/forms/inbox:/workdir -w /workdir/ brnlab/aultman-pdftk ./'.basename($files[$i]).' burst output ./pg_%03d.pdf';`

Oddly the return on the $command when running this as a cron or mailbox command is blank, so I am not sure if there is an error or not.  It does not appear to hang up.  Any ideas on the best way to diagnose the issue further?